# Use of MODULE_FIRMWARE(filename) macro in Linux modules

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, kernel-modules

What is the use of the `MODULE_FIRMWARE(filename)` macro in Linux kernel modules?

Answer (score 5):

It declares a firmware file that may be required by the module. See [its definition in `module.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/module.h#L181); the firmware is loaded by `request_firmware()`. `MODULE_FIRMWARE` is mostly used for documentation purposes, as far as the kernel is concerned: the information provided via this macro appears in the module information, as shown for example by `modinfo`. External tools may use the list of firmware files, *e.g.* to include them as appropriate in an initramfs.

Firmware files referenced in this fashion contain firmware for the device managed by the module; this is typically binary code intended for whatever co-processor (anything from a micro-controller to a GPU) is on the device.

Comment: The declaration can be used by e.g. initramfs generators: if a module is chosen to be included in initramfs and it requires firmware to work, the `MODULE_FIRMWARE(filename)` declaration will allow the initramfs generator to automatically include the correct firmware file to initramfs too.